# Reduction of order problem with nonhomogeneous second order DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am studying reduction of order from here:
http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/ReductionofOrder.aspx
But this tutorial uses homogeneous examples to explain reduction of order. Now I am trying to apply reduction of order to this question:

$(D^2+1)y=\sec^3(x)$ use $y=v\sin(x)$

Please guide me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume it is $y′′+y$

Comment: I am not sure either

Comment: Yes this is one of my homework questions and it is written as above and it says solve it by reduction of order.

Comment: It is correct, $\sin(x)$ is a homogeneous solution. So, letting $y = v \sin x$, find the second derivative using the product rule, substitute back into the DEQ and solve. Do you know how to find the second derivative using the product rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

We have:

$$y = v \sin x$$

This gives us:

- $y' = v \ cos x + v' \sin x$
- $y'' = -v \sin x + v' \cos x + v' \ cos x + v'' \sin x$

Substituting into the ODE and simplifying, yields the new DEQ:

$$v'' \sin x + 2 v' \cos x = (\sec x)^3$$

Now, solve this using an Integrating Factor.

**Spoiler**

> $v(x) = c_1 \cot x + c_2 + \dfrac{\tan x}{2}$

Of course, recall that the final solution is given by $y = v \sin x$.

Please fill in the details as this hint steps you through the entire problem.

Comment: I have substituted first and second derivatives of $y$ into equation: $(v''*sin(x) + 2*v'*cos(x) - v*sin(x))*v*sin(x)=sec(x)^3$ but I can not simplify it. Can you help abit more?

Comment: Recall, you have $y'' + y$ from $D^2 + 1$. That is likely your issue since you do not have $y'$, which would show up as $D$. Clear?

Comment: @OlcayErtaş: Your DEQ written out is $y'' + y = (\sec x)^3$. Is that clear? The $D's$ are a shorthand notation.

Comment: This is how axactly the question is written: $(D^2 + 1)y = sec(x)^3$

Comment: Which it should be interpreted as: $(y''+ y)y=sec(x)^3$ wright?

Comment: No, $(D^2+1)y$ means $y'' + y$. It is using a shorthand operator notation. For example $(D^2 - 3D +1)y$ means $y'' - 3y' + y$. I am surprised there is nothing in your book or notes on this. See, for example: http://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-18-008-calculus-revisited-complex-variables-differential-equations-and-linear-algebra-fall-2011/study-materials/MITRES_18_008_supp_notes04.pdf (see (4) and (5). So, your DEQ is $y'' + y = (\sec x)^3$. Is that clear?

Comment: OH! OK! I see now! I will try again with that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$$\xi \equiv y' + {\rm i}y.\quad\xi' = y'' + {\rm i}y'
= y'' + {\rm i}\left(\xi - {\rm i}y\right) = y'' + y + {\rm i}\xi.\quad$ Then,
$y'' + y = \xi' - {\rm i}\xi$.

You will recover $y$ as $y = \Im\xi$.
$$
\xi' - \ic\xi = \sec^{3}\pars{x}\quad\imp\quad\totald{\bracks{\expo{-\ic x}\xi}}{x}
=\expo{-\ic x}\sec^{3}\pars{x}
$$
$$
\expo{-\ic x}\xi = \int\expo{-\ic x}\sec^{3}\pars{x} + \mbox{a constant}.
$$
Let's say, $\underline{\tt\mbox{for example}}$, we know ${\rm y}\pars{0}$ and
${\rm y}'\pars{0}$. Then, we'll know
$\xi\pars{0} = {\rm y}'\pars{0} + \ic{\rm y}\pars{0}$:
\begin{align}
&\expo{-\ic x}\xi\pars{x} - \xi\pars{0}
=
\int_{0}^{x}\expo{-\ic t}\sec^{3}\pars{t}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]\imp\
{\rm y}\pars{x}
&=
{\rm y}\pars{0}\cos\pars{x} + {\rm y}'\pars{0}\sin\pars{x}
+
\Im\int_{0}^{x}\expo{\ic\pars{x - t}}\sec^{3}\pars{t}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=
{\rm y}\pars{0}\cos\pars{x} + {\rm y}'\pars{0}\sin\pars{x}
+
\int_{0}^{x}\bracks{%
\sin\pars{x}\sec^{2}\pars{t} - \cos\pars{x}\,{\sin\pars{t} \over \cos^{3}\pars{t}}}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=
{\rm y}\pars{0}\cos\pars{x} + {\rm y}'\pars{0}\sin\pars{x}
+
\sin\pars{x}\tan\pars{x}
- 
\cos\pars{x}\bracks{-\,{1 \over 2\cos^{2}\pars{x}} + \half}
\end{align}
$$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
{\rm y}\pars{x}
=
\bracks{{\rm y}\pars{0} - \half}\cos\pars{x} + {\rm y}'\pars{0}\sin\pars{x}
+
\sin\pars{x}\tan\pars{x} + \half\sec\pars{x}}
$$